# How do I interact with a slice in a Core Plot pie chart?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you enable touch selection of a section in a Core Plot pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506544/how-do-you-enable-touch-selection-of-a-section-in-a-core-plot-pie-chart)

In looking through the Core Plot examples, I don't see a good sample for how to do touch-based interaction with the plots.  In particular, I would like to be able to select a particular slice from a pie chart.

Does anyone know how to do this or have an example of this process?

Comment: refer this link: http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/04/drawing-pie-charts.html hope it helps

Comment: What's unclear within the sample applications?  The `CPTestApp-iPhone` example shows step-by-step how to create a pie chart within the `CPTestAppPieChartController.m` source file.

Comment: Im quite new to this. The methods are not descriptive. I need a interactive graph. some thing which handles event. let say, highlight the portion of pie chart selected and showing some details of the portion.

Comment: So the problem that you are having is not with the drawing of the pie chart, but how to select a particular wedge in response to a touch event?

Comment: @Brad Yes. Need to handle some events on touching the wedges. Is there any tutorials for that?

Comment: no. I need core-plot interactive graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe my answer for another question regarding this topic may help you:

[How do you enable touch selection of a section in a Core Plot pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506544/finding-out-the-selectted-section-of-a-pie-chart-in-iphone/4685322#4685322)

Comment: Is there any method to interact with bar graph? and scatter plot graph?

Comment: Yes, there is the CPBarPlotDelegate with its method (void)barPlot:(CPBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index. Have a look into CPBarPlot.h