# How do you enable touch selection of a section in a Core Plot pie chart?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I am using the Core Plot framework to draw a pie chart, and am having no issues in drawing the pie chart itself.

However, I need the pie chart to be interactive in nature, i.e., if I tap on any particular section in the pie chart, it should trigger the navigation to a page showing details of that particular section.

I tried using the method `-(void)pieChart:sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:`, but that delegate method was never called.  What do I need to enable this touch interaction?

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented pie piece selection in my iPad app with CorePlot 0.2.2. Your guess to use
**(void)pieChart:sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:** is correct, but maybe you have forgotten
to declare the following two things:

- Does your controller declares the **CPPieChartDelegate** protocol?
- Did you tell the pie chart that your controller is its **delegate**?

My view controller looks like this in the header declaration:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController < CPPieChartDataSource,
                                                   CPPieChartDelegate,
                                                   ... >
{
   ...
   CPXYGraph*          pieGraph;
   CPGraphHostingView* pieView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CPGraphHostingView* pieView;

- (void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

The creation of the pie chart is called during the **(void)viewDidLoad**, where I set the data source and the delegate of the pie chart:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [self createPie];
}

-(void)createPie {
   pieGraph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   pieGraph.axisSet = nil;
   self.pieView.hostedGraph = pieGraph;

   CPPieChart *pieChart = [[CPPieChart alloc] init];

   // This is important in order to have your slice selection handler called!
   pieChart.delegate = self;

   pieChart.dataSource = self;

   pieChart.pieRadius = 80.0;
   [pieGraph addPlot:pieChart];
   [pieChart release];
}

- (void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
   // Do whatever you need when the pie slice has been selected.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the last `corePlot framework (1.4)` i could not find `CPPieChart` but I fixed with `CPTPieChartDelegate`:

```
@interface CPDFirstViewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPieChartDelegate, ...>
```

and this method:

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
  // Put your action here
}
```

`CPPieChartDelegate` is not recognized any more as Delegate from Xcode, using `CorePlot 1.4`

Hope it helps.

dom

Comment: The Core Plot class prefix changed from "CP" to "CPT".

Comment: Thanks: it looks like if you google "corePlot examples" you will always run into old examples, or old discussion threads. Hopefully this note will help "iOS learners" (like me ;-) )